# Select Into Temp Table using Row_Number Over

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to fill a new table with record from a query using the Row_Number Over(Partition in SQL Server.  The code is a cut down version but I get an error near ')'..  The Select statement works ok on its own..  Obviously I am missing something so can anyone advise what I am doing wrong?  Many many thanks as usual..

Derek

```
Select * into djtest333 from (SELECT TenancyPK,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TenancyPK  ORDER BY TenancyPK) as RowNumber
  FROM Tenancy)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please always write which error message you get.
In this case you have to give the select statement an alias. For example:

```
Select * into djtest333 from (SELECT TenancyPK,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TenancyPK  ORDER BY TenancyPK) as RowNumber
  FROM Tenancy) AS A
```

Comment: As simple as that..  Sorry my error message was there but not clear and precise..  Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Add alias to your subquery:

```
Select * into djtest333 from (SELECT TenancyPK,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TenancyPK  ORDER BY TenancyPK) as RowNumber
  FROM Tenancy) AS A
```